# Sharepoint Ribbon: Circumventing Context sensitivity

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, ribbon

I'm new to sharepoint development and I'm trying to modify the behaviour of the Sharepoint ribbon. As you all know, the ribbon is such that when something else gains focus(e.g a list item), the ribbon automatically switches to an appropriate tab or tab group(e.g the List tools tab group).

I'd like to disable this constant switching of tabs and make the browse tab to always be the active tab, unless the user explicitly clicks on another tab.

I've tried doing the following in the Page_Load() of a Usercontrol, but it only works once, when the page is initially loaded. What am I doing wrong? More importantly, how could I do it right, if at all?

Basically, I'm hoping someone could point me to the event that's fired when the context changes and the ribbon switches, and how I could hook up to this event and force the ribbon to switch back to the browse tab.

```
protected void Page_Load()
        {
            string showBrowseTabScript = string.Empty;
            showBrowseTabScript = @"
                                function ShowBrowseTab() {

                                         var ribbon = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_ribbon();
                                         SelectRibbonTab(""Ribbon.Read"", true);
                                      }

                                      SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {

                                         var pm = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
                                         pm.add_ribbonInited(function() {

                                            ShowBrowseTab();
                                         });

                                         var ribbon = null;
                                         try
                                         {
                                            ribbon = pm.get_ribbon();

                                         }

                                         catch (e) { }

                                         if (!ribbon) {

                                            if (typeof(_ribbonStartInit) == ""function"")

                                               _ribbonStartInit(_ribbon.initialTabId, false, null);
                                         }
                                         else {

                                            ShowBrowseTab();
                                         }

                                      },

                                      ""sp.ribbon.js"");
                                ";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "BrowseTabScript", showBrowseTabScript, true);
        }
```

Comment: Executing on load once would be the expected behavior from calling executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded (ie you don't have anything event wise to detect the active tab changed).  That being said what problem are you trying to save by changing this behavior that improves the user experience?  If most users won't need the ribbon you might be better off just hiding the whole container div.

Comment: @KenHenderson, the users need the ribbon, they just prefer to switch tabs themselves, instead of the tabs switching contextually. I'm hoping someone could point me to the event that's fired when the context changes and the ribbon switches, and how I could hook up to this event and force the ribbon to switch back to the browse tab. I'll edit my question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to the problem, in case anyone is interested.

Taking Ken Henderson's suggestion into consideration, I was able to achieve what I've been trying to do, although I achieved this by modifying the code of the SP.Ribbon.js and SP.Ribbon.debug.js files. I'm using the SP.Ribbon.debug.js to show my solution below, since it is not as cryptic as the SP.Ribbon.js.

Basically, I use the code below to trick the ribbon into thinking that the User is on a different tab and has clicked on the "Browse" tab. You will notice that I set the old tab information in the code. It will still work without me doing this, but I did it just in case the ribbon needs that information for something else I'm not aware of. This code, in combination with the Page_Load() function I posted in the first post, cause the ribbon to behave just like I needed it to.

```
SP.Ribbon.PageManager.prototype = {

    executeRootCommand: function (commandId, properties, commandInfo, root) {
        ULSMg8: ;
        var $v_0;
        if (!SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(commandInfo) && commandId !== 'RibbonEvent' && (commandId !== 'CommandContextChanged' || (!SP.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(properties) && properties['ChangedByUser']))) {
// My changes to SP.Ribbon

if (properties["ChangedByUser"] === false) {
            properties["ChangedByUser"] = true;
            var $NewContextId = properties["NewContextId"];
            var $NewContextCommand = properties["NewContextCommand"];
            properties["OldContextId"] = $NewContextId;
            properties["OldContextCommand"] = $NewContextCommand;
            properties["NewContextId"] = "Ribbon.Read";
            properties["NewContextCommand"] = "ReadTab";
            SelectRibbonTab("Ribbon.Read", true);
        }

// End of changes to SP.Ribbon

            // the rest of the code has been ommitted for clarity
        return $v_0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge SharePoint doesn't expose any events to detect when the ribbon tabs update (either tabs adding/removing or which is active).  At least I was unable to find any a few weeks ago when I was trying to detect when tabs were added/removed (I didn't care which was active just the number/width of them).

(Sorry for the lack of details, the SharePoint dev environment at the office is unavailable at the moment so I can't look up the details very easily.)

There are two possiblities for solving this problem (each has risks/problems):

#### Override JS Functionality

Figure out what JavaScript function is being called when the user clicks on an item that updates the ribbon.  You might be able to replace that function with your own that provides the behavior you want.  This would be similar in concept to a custom master page that scrolls on the window and has to change the behavior of the width sizing.  I'm unable to verify the details at the moment but it looks like the function is called SingleItemSelect in core.js.

This could be a problem if you have exceptions to when to override this behavior and if MS changes anything in the future you're implementation may break and/or need to be updated.

#### Add your own event handler

In your JavaScript code try to find an appropriate DOM event to attach an event handler to in the ribbon to detect when MS's code changes the ribbon.  There is a good chance given the limitations of the DOM events that there will not be an event to attach a handler to.  You may end up adding a function that is called periodically (polling loop/timer) that detects ribbon tab changes and resets the active one.

Honestly this will not work well since there will be flickering as MS's ribbon code changes the active tab and your's changes it back.  Additionally you'll need to detect when the user clicks on a tab so that you don't undo their changes.

#### Wrap up

Honestly I would push back and get this requirement changed so that the ribbon behavior works the way MS designed and not try to fight it.  If the ribbon showing up when the user clicks on an item is really an issue then I would propose to the client that instead of forcing the `Browse` tab as active to add an additional link in the ribbon area somewhere that allows the ribbon (or at least the part that expands over the title area) to be toggled as hidden/shown independently of what MS's JavaScript is doing to the ribbon.